# how to add data labels to a nvd3 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I am building a very simple barchart using nvd3. And I was trying to add data labels on top of the bar chart. I added a .selectALl section, however, the data label still doesn't show up. Please let me know if you see any error in my code. Thanks!

```
<div id="chart2" style="height:88%">
            <svg ></svg>    
            <script>    
                var myData = {'Label': ['AC', 'BB', 'GS'], 'Price': [0.201, 0.251, 0.082]}; 

                nv.addGraph(function() {
                var chart2 = nv.models.multiBarChart()

                  .reduceXTicks(false)   //If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered.
                  .rotateLabels(0)      //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
                  .showControls(false)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
                  .groupSpacing(0.1)    //Distance between each group of bars.
                  .stacked(false)


                chart2.xAxis.rotateLabels(45);          
                chart2.yAxis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(".1%"));

                chart2.duration(500);

                chart2.legend.maxKeyLength(100);

                d3.select('#chart2 svg')
                    .datum(exampleData())
                    .call(chart2)


                 svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(myData )
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")                 
                    .text(function(d) { return d.Price; })
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.Label) + xScale.range() / 2; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d.Price) + 12; })
                    .style("fill", "white");



                nv.utils.windowResize(chart2.update);

                return chart2;




            });

            </script>
        </div>
```